# How to solve modular division when there is no inverse?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I was reading a simple interview quesion on geeksforgeeks [find loop in linked list using two pointer](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-and-remove-loop-in-a-linked-list/), probably a lot of you guys already heard of it. I understand that if you have 2 pointers, one is moving twice as fast as another one, they will always meet inside the loop.Simple math I derived could explain it:

let the loop be of size 4, the statement says **"no matter where the two pointer starts in the loop (possible positions:$\{0,1,2,3\}$), they will always meet up"**, let $a$ be the starting position of slower pointer and $b$ be the starting position of fast pointer, then we have

$a+X = b+2X (mod4)$ and we want to find $X$, I simply rearrange the formula to $a-b = X (mod4)$ this has a solution for any choice of $a,b$

**TL;DR** my question is that what if I now have a pointer that moves **three** times faster than the slow pointer, so the equation becomes:$a+X = b+3X (mod4) -> a-b = 2X (mod4)$, well $gcd(2,4)!=1$, so there is no $2^{-1}$ that I can multiply on the left hand side, yet in this case if $a = 0, b = 1$ there is no solution, and $a = 0, b = 2$ a valid answer is $X = 1$

what is the relation between $a,b$ in order to have a solution(test if $(a-b)$ equals any of $2*\{0,1,2,3\}$)? how should I express the solution $X$? what do we do in general when we have a no-coprime number, but we want to move it to the other side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modular equation $$(a-b)\equiv 2x \pmod{4}$$
has no solutions if $a-b$ is odd, and two solutions (mod $n$) if $a-b$ is even.  More generally, for $$(a-b)\equiv mx \pmod{n}$$
then there will be no solutions if $\gcd(m,n)$ does not divide $(a-b)$, and $\frac{n}{\gcd(m,n)}$ solutions (mod $n$) if $\gcd(m,n)$ does divide $(a-b)$.

Comment: Quick question, how you type the modular equal sign?

Comment: \equiv.  If you want to see how people type things, hit "edit" (once you have enough reputation)

Comment: is there a theorem that I can look up? that says it should have $n/gcd(m,n)$ solutions (hopefully it comes with some proof)?

Comment: See "Concrete Mathematics" by Grahm, Knuth, Patashnik.  $cx\equiv cy\pmod{cn}$ if and only if $x\equiv y\pmod{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, $(a - b) \equiv mx\ mod\ n$ has $gcd(m,n)$ solutions ($mod\ n$) if $gcd(m,n)$ divides  $(a - b)$ . The solutions are in arithmetic progression with difference between consecutive terms being $\frac{n}{gcd(m,n)}$. (notice this is correction to the number of solutions given in accepted answer)